# Trim whitespace characters from within a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, removing-whitespace

I have a string with an unknown combination of whitespace characters (`\t`, `\n` or space) between words. For example:

```
string str = "Hello \t\t  \n \t    \t World! \tPlease Help.";
```

I want to replace each sequence of inner whitespace characters with a single space:

```
string str = "Hello World! Please Help.";
```

Does .NET provide a built-in way to do this? If not, how can I do this via C#?

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, @"\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following regex replacement

```
string original = ...;
string replaced = Regex.Replace(original, @"\s+", " ");
```

This replace each group of white space characters (`\s`) with a single space.  You can find other helpful character groups here

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: `@"\s{2,}"` could be somewhat more efficient.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes why would that be more efficient (genuinely curios)

Comment: Beacause it will not have to replace all single white spaces by another single white space. However it will not replace `\t` by a `" "`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes i think the replacement of `\t` has to be done in order to maintain semantics outlined by the OP.  It's not 100% clear but that's how I read it.

Comment: Yes, this would do it `@"\s{2,}|\t|\n"`. However, it is probably not worth the complication.

Answer (score 1):

string trimmed = Regex.Replace(original, @"\s+", " ");

Reference - http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace-spaces

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in method to achieve this, but you can use regular expressions:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a slightly different approach. A bit more wordy (and currently in VB) but it allows me to easily do all kinds of exclusions such as symbols or punctuation or combinations of the categories. It also keeps me from having to learn regular expressions.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Text

Public Module StringExclusions

        <Extension()> Public Function CharsToString(ByVal val As IEnumerable(Of Char)) As String
            Dim bldr As New StringBuilder()
            bldr.Append(val.ToArray)
            Return bldr.ToString()
        End Function

        <Extension()> Public Function RemoveCategories(ByVal val As String, ByVal categories As IEnumerable(Of UnicodeCategory)) As String
            Return (From chr As Char In val.ToCharArray Where Not categories.Contains(Char.GetUnicodeCategory(chr))).CharsToString
        End Function

        Public Function WhiteSpaceCategories() As IEnumerable(Of UnicodeCategory)
            Return New List(Of UnicodeCategory) From {UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator, UnicodeCategory.LineSeparator, UnicodeCategory.Control}
        End Function
        '...Other commonly used categories removed for brevity.
    End Module
```

And a couple of tests.

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void RemoveCharacters()
    {
        String testObj = "a \a b \b c \f d \n e \r f \t g \v h";
        Assert.AreEqual(@"abcdefgh", testObj.RemoveCategories(Strings.WhiteSpaceCategories()));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void KeepValidCharacters()
    {
        String testObj = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`12334567890-=~!@#$%^&*()_+[]\{}|;':,./<>?"  + "\"";
        Assert.AreEqual(@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`12334567890-=~!@#$%^&*()_+[]\{}|;':,./<>?" + "\"", testObj.RemoveCategories(Strings.WhiteSpaceCategories()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a faster alternative without using Regex:

```
string replaced = String.Join(" ", str.Split(
   new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: Can you provide evidence that your non-Regex method is faster than the offered Regex-based answers?

Answer (score -1):

Fastest and general way to do this (line terminators, tabs will be processed as well). Regex powerful facilities don't really needed to solve this problem, but Regex can decrease performance.

```
String  
.Join
(" ",     
  new string  
  (stringToRemoveWhiteSpaces
      .Select
      (
         c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c) ? ' ' : c
      )
      .ToArray<char>()
  )
  .Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
)
```